# How to change Form initialValues and Fields based on selection in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, formik, yup

I have an object like this :

```
const initialValues = {
    "Name": "",
    "Price": "",
    "Quantity": "",
    "Details": {
        "Light": "",
        "Watering": "",
        "Maintenance": "",
        "WhereToGrow": "",
    },
    "BrowseImg": "",
    "MainImg": "",
    "Tags": "",
    "Category": "Plant",
    "SubCategory": ""
}
```

I am using React Formik library in my Form Component, I am rendering `selection`& `Details object` like this:

```
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <FormControl required>
      <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-required-label">Category</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-required-label"
        id="demo-simple-select-required"
        value={values.Category !== "undefined" ? values.Category : ""}
        label="Category *"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFieldValue("Category", e.target.value);
        }}
        autoWidth
        name="Category"
        defaultValue=""
      >
        <MenuItem value="">
          <em>None</em>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={"Plant"}>Plant</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={"Planters"}>Planters</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={"Seeds"}>Seeds</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  </Grid>
  <FieldArray name="Details">
    <Grid container spacing={2} sx={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Typography>Details</Typography>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextFieldWrapper
          name={
            values.Category !== "Planters"
              ? `Details.Light`
              : `Details.Material`
          }
          label={values.Category !== "Planters" ? `Light` : "Material"}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextFieldWrapper
          name={
            values.Category !== "Planters"
              ? `Details.Watering`
              : `Details.Build`
          }
          label={values.Category !== "Planters" ? `Watering` : "Build"}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextFieldWrapper
          name={
            values.Category !== "Planters"
              ? `Details.Maintenance`
              : `Details.PlanterHeight`
          }
          label={
            values.Category !== "Planters" ? `Maintenance` : "Planter Height"
          }
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextFieldWrapper
          name={
            values.Category !== "Planters"
              ? `Details.WhereToGrow`
              : `Details.PlanterWidth`
          }
          label={
            values.Category !== "Planters" ? `Where To Grow` : "Planter Width"
          }
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </FieldArray>
```

Now, I need to change `initialValues` object when `"Planters"` is selected to :

```
{
    "Name": "",
    "Price": "",
    "Quantity": "",
    "Details": {
        "Material": "",
        "Build": "",
        "PlanterHeight": "",
        "PlanterWidth": ""
    },
    "BrowseImg": "",
    "MainImg": "",
    "Tags": "",
    "Category": "Planters",
    "SubCategory": ""
}
```

I tried this to change key Name in `initialValues` object like this:

```
    const Context = () => {
      const { values } = useFormikContext();

      useEffect(() => {
        if (values.Category === "Planters") {
          delete Object.assign(initialValues.Details, {
            Material: initialValues.Details.Light,
          })["Light"];
          delete Object.assign(initialValues.Details, {
            Build: initialValues.Details.Watering,
          })["Watering"];
          delete Object.assign(initialValues.Details, {
            PlanterHeight: initialValues.Details.Maintenance,
          })["Maintenance"];
          delete Object.assign(initialValues.Details, {
            PlanterWidth: initialValues.Details.WhereToGrow,
          })["WhereToGrow"];

          console.log("VALUES FORMIK CONTEXT", values);
          console.log("INITIALVALUES", initialValues);
          console.log(
            "INITIAL VALUES DETAILS ",
            initialValues.Details.Material
          );
        }
      }, [values]);
      return null;
    };
```

changing name when `values.Category` is Planters throws Formik Error as follows:

```
Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not quite correct approach, and it's not good idea for me to change set of fields in a form on-the-fly - you'll have problems supporting your own tangled code, this `useEffect` is pure mess.

Keep in mind that form data you use for UI may differ from data you send to backend and can be transformed right before you make a request. Actually `initialValues` is for initializing your form and should not be changed from inside the form. I'd create universal set of field.

For example, I'd change data initial data like this

```
// read-only array to render Select, add as much item as you like.
// In general, since it's just an array for options,
// it can be safely extracted to external constant
// and may not present in initialData. 
Categories: [
 {
  name 'Planers',
  selected: true,
 },
 {
   name: 'Plants'
 } 
],
SelectedCategory: 'Planers', // since selected is true 
Planters: {
  "Material": "",
  "Build": "",
  "PlanterHeight": "",
  "PlanterWidth": ""
},
Plants: {
  "Light": "",
  "Watering": "",
  "Maintenance": "",
  "WhereToGrow": "",
}
```

And then in your form

```
// ...
const { values, handleChange, handleBlur } = useFormikContext();

<Select
  onChange={handleChange} // or your own handler
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  name="SelectedCategory"
>
{values.Categories.map(({name, selected}) => (
  <MenuItem
   key={name}
   selected={selected}
  >
   {name}
  </MenuItem >
))}
</Select>
```

and in the same component two or more sets of fields. Each set is rendered according to `SelectedCategory` value. There's no need to change or reset values in sets of fields when `SelectedCategory` changes - you can remove or reset the fields on the stage of sending the data.

```
if (values.SelectedCategory === 'Planers') {
  // render set of fields for Planers
}
if (values.SelectedCategory === 'Plants') {
  // render set of fields for Plants
}
```

And `onSubmit` you can transform your filed values as you like:

```
<Formik
  initialValues
  onSubmit={(values, {resetForm}) => {
      const transformedDataForAsyncRequest = yourCustomDataTransducer(values);
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        data: transformedDataForAsyncRequest
      })
        .then(() => {resetForm()})
        .catch((e) => {console.log(e)})
    }
  }
```